# Xfce4 themes not shown in Debian Buster

Tags: debian, xfce

I have Xfce4 installed on one machine using Debian stretch, using the Platinum them.  I installed Debian Buster on a new machine and selected Xfce4. Theme Platinum does not exist in the list of available themes.  I understand that themes are found in package xfwm4-themes and, indeed, this package exists in Stretch and had been installed in my system.  Looking through Debian Buster I cannot find xfwm4-themes.  The Debian release notes do not suggest any changes to Xfce and version numbers match on my two systems.

Is this a bug in the release?  How do I get the themes installed?

Comment: According to the [Debian package site](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=xfwm4-theme&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), `xfwm4-themes` is not available for Debian Buster. I am unsure why this would be the case but if [Platinum9](https://github.com/grassmunk/Platinum9) is the theme you are looking for you can always manually install it.

Comment: Thanks @kemotep. I had checked the Debian site and thats really what drives my question.  I does occur to me, though, that I could copy the themes from my Stretch machine.  It still looks like a bug in the release.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that xfwm4-themes has been dropped from buster because it is no longer supported [upstream](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=916394). I've downloaded and installed the .deb from my stretch machine and so far it's working. I guess I risk some kind of compatibility problem when xfce goes up a version, but I'll live with that for now.